# AutoLISP drag n drop command

Tags: autocad, autolisp

I am writing a **lisp** for **autocad** and I am in the final stage to create it. I want to write a command that is the same as dragging and dropping a text file into your drawing (this creates an mtext in your drawing with the content of the text file as mtext). Does anyone know the command?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drag and drop handler for the AutoCAD document window is not a command. There is no built-in command that creates an mtext entity from the contents of a text file.